# Cypher(neo4j): Compare a column with a date, only if the column content is parsable

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to compare a column with a date, just in case it's parseable and comparable, for example:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.last_used = "no_information" OR datetime(n.last_used) < datetime(datetime())
RETURN n.name, n.last_used
```

Assuming the `last_used` column content can be either a "no_information" string or a valid date/time string.

I still get an error:

> Text cannot be parsed to a DateTime "no_information"

Is it possible to somehow skip the parsing and comparison in case the string is not a valid datetime?

Comment: Your query is working fine, on my system.

Comment: what is your neo4j version? The query is also working when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the ideal would be to have the date already in datetime format,
in order to check the data type, for example via the Apoc procedure
[apoc.meta.isType](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.meta/apoc.meta.isType/) ,

a very simple way to check a string could be to use the [regular expressions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#query-where-regex),
for example (in this case i check "yyyy-mm-dd", it could be more complex, in case)

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.last_used =~ "\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}.*" and datetime(n.last_used) < datetime(datetime()) 
RETURN n.name, n.last_used
    UNION 
MATCH (n) 
WHERE n.last_used = "no_information"  
RETURN n.name, n.last_used
```

N.b.: I used `UNION` clause because the below one should works too, but it give me an error for some reason.

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.last_used = "no_information" 
   OR (n.last_used =~ "\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}.*" AND datetime(n.last_used) < datetime(datetime()) ) RETURN n.name, n.last_used
```

---

Alternatively, maybe you could write a [custom procedure](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/) which call the `datetime(..)` function and, in case of exception, catch it and returns `null`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If your datetime format is like below:
2022-06-01T12:50:35.556+0100

Then you can use this query:

```
MATCH (n) where (n.last_used =~ "[0-9\\-T\\.\\+\\:]+"  
    and datetime( n.last_used ) < datetime(datetime()) ) 
    OR n.last_used = "no_information" 
RETURN n
```

The regexp says filter only last_used that contains numbers from 0 to 9 or a hyphen or letter T or a dot or plus or colon.

Sample result:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"n"                                                           │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"testing","last_used":"no_information"}               │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"testing3","last_used":"2022-06-01T12:50:35.556+0100"}│
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```